# Loop through array and adding sums of each section

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have 11 checkboxes that are split up into 4 different categories. Each category has 3 check-boxes to choose from except for the last, which has 2. I want to check if a check-box within each category is checked and find out how many of them are checked within that category. I might be over thinking this one but so far I have this as my JS:

```
//I initially receive the checkbox values as a string that has 1 for checked and 0 for not checked.

var split_string = checkbox_string.split(",").map(Number);
console.log(split_string);

var sec = [];
var total = 0;
var split_int=[];
var sliced = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 3 ; ++i) {
    sec[i] = split_string.splice(0,3);
    console.log(sec[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < sec[i].length; ++j){
    sliced = sec[i][j];
    total += sliced;
  }
  console.log("total= "+ total);
    window['section' + i] = total;

}
```

So as of right now I'm pretty close, although I'm sure there is a simpler way of doing this. I split the string into 4 arrays (ex.[1,0,1] [0,0,1] [1,1,1] [1,0]). Then I take each individual number from each array and add it to the total.

As of right now it will return the 1st three added, then it returns the 2nd three added to the first three on its 2nd loop. So for example total=2 the first time around then total=3 the 2nd time around, but I want total the 2nd time around to be only based on the 2nd array (so it would be 1 if following the ex. above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function summer(p,c,i) {
  if( i%3==0 ) p.push(0);
  p[p.length-1] += c;
  return p;
}

var split_string = [1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0];
split_string.reduce(summer,[]); // [2, 1, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I might like this solution better then mine. Didn't even occur to me to check if divisible by 3. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm dumb, all I needed to add was total = 0 at the bottom of the array. But I'd still be interested if there is better/more simple ways of doing this.